# Why does a poster appear over my video when I move the mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying made the following code using mouseover/mouseout to play and pause an HTML video.

```
  <div>
    <video id="video" controls width="50%" class="border" onmouseout="Stop()" onmouseover="Play()" controls="false">
        <source src="https://www.errorerror.studio/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/ee.st-honesty-clip-00.mp4" preload="auto" type="video/mp4" autoplay></source>
    </video>

  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function Play() {
     $('#video').get(0).play();
 }
 function Stop() {
      $('#video').get(0).pause();
  }
```

What I want is everytime I mouseout the mouse, a poster or image appears over the video. (Like the following example in this site: https://www.lawebdecanada.com/work/featured/ )

I am note able to do it, hopelly someone can help me to figure out how to make it.
This is my code on codepen: https://codepen.io/felixgonzalo/pen/abzQPjZ

Thanks!

Comment: The codepen appears to play and pause as expected on mouseover and mouseout.  What exactly is not working?

Comment: @Taplar what I want is whenever I mouseout from the video, it appears like a poster/placeholder image (like this example:  https://www.lawebdecanada.com/work/featured/ )

Comment: and where in your question have you made an attempt to implement that logic?  Your question, in its current form, is not asking for help with a problem, but asking others to augment your existing code.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Questions are expected to have made an attempt at the behaviour they desire.

Comment: Sorry @Taplar, I tryied to figure out but I couldn't. I get what you mean. Excuse me if I bother you!

Comment: It's not a particular bother of mine, but it is an agreed upon community practice that we are all expected to follow.

Comment: I will keep in mind, thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an element cover another you can place them in the same container and use `position: absolute` and a higher `z-index` on the overlay. Then under the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events (note: *not* `mouseout` and `mouseover`) you can hide/show the overlay and play./pause the video. Try this:

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.video-container');

container.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  this.querySelector('.overlay').classList.remove('hide');
  this.querySelector('.video').pause();
});

container.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  this.querySelector('.overlay').classList.add('hide');
  this.querySelector('.video').play();
});
```

```css
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
.video-container video {
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
}
.overlay.hide {
  display: none;
}
.overlay p {
  margin-top: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-container">
  <video class="video" controls class="border" controls="false">
    <source src="https://www.errorerror.studio/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/ee.st-honesty-clip-00.mp4" preload="auto" type="video/mp4" autoplay />
  </video>
  <div class="overlay">
    <p>Hover me</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, it's just what I was trying to figure out! Pretty simple and easy, thank yu for your support!

Answer (score 1):

You can reset [currentTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) value to `0` in `Stop` function:

```
$('#video').prop('currentTime', 0)
```

```js
function Play() {
     $('#video').get(0).play();
}
function Stop() {
    $('#video').prop('currentTime', 0).get(0).pause();
}
```

```css
video::-webkit-media-controls {


    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div>
    <video id="video" controls width="50%" class="border" onmouseout="Stop()" onmouseover="Play()" controls="false">
        <source src="https://www.errorerror.studio/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/ee.st-honesty-clip-00.mp4" preload="auto" type="video/mp4" autoplay></source>
    </video>
           
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tân, I implement your code on the Rory's example code and it works perfectly, thanks for your expertise! very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have made an example based on your CodePen modify little things and added an overlay using CSS transition for the hover effect, hope this help~

```js
function Play() {
     $('#video').get(0).play();
}
function Stop() {
    $('#video').get(0).pause();
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3s opacity;
}

.overlay:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay" onmouseout="Stop()" onmouseover="Play()">
      Overlay
    </div>
    <video id="video" controls class="border" controls="false">
        <source src="https://www.errorerror.studio/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/ee.st-honesty-clip-00.mp4" preload="auto" type="video/mp4" autoplay></source>
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, different of what I was looking for what also interesting. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for @RoryMcCrossan figure out! I have updated it and now should be the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The website you linked achieves this by having a parent element that contains a div element with the image and another div element with the video.

CSS is used to hide the div element like so:

```
.parent:hover .preview {
    display: none;
}
```

For the rest you can use the JavaScript code you have, although using HTML attributes to control events is discouraged.